# Distance from each cell of value 1 to each cell of value 0

Tags: raster

I would like to figure out the distance (in terms number of cells) from each cell in a raster of value 1 to each cell of value 0. Ideally the output would be another raster, where the value of each cell would be the shortest distance to a cell of value 0. Cells that were 0 in the original raster would assume the value of 0 since they are technically 0 cells away from a cell of value 0.

However, so far my search for how to do this has been unsuccessful. I believe that the proximity() command in QGIS does this, but to use the r extension to QGIS (RQGIS) requires downloading several items (SAGA, GRASS, and QGIS) via the command line, and I have been getting errors trying to install SAGA so would love it if someone knew of a way to do this exclusively with R.

Here is a raster containing 1's and 0's to serve as a reproducible example of this problem:

```
library(raster)
#create raster and add 1's and 0's
land <- raster(matrix(0, 8, 10), xmn=408027.5, xmx=413027.5, ymn=4370000, 
ymx=4374000)
land[4:8, 2:5] <- 1
land[2:3, 8:9] <- 1
land[1,0:10] <- 1
land[is.na(land[])] <- 0
#plot the raster
plot(land)
```

[image: raster]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

raster::gridDistance gives you the shortest distance when having to go through neighboring cell centers

```
g <- gridDistance(land, 1)
plot(g)
```

[image]

Otherwise, shortest path distance can be computed with

```
landna <- reclassify(land, cbind(0,NA))
d <- distance(landna)
```

And see the `gdistance` package for more distance computations.